# Emacs regexp to join lines, grabbing the newline character as well

Tags: regex, emacs

What would be the regexp syntax to grab "The equal sign at the end of a line (`=$`), **plus** the "newline character" immediately following it"?

I have badly formatted (broken really) text like this:

```
Tiens, encore du HTML, batard rouge, et un charact=C3=A8re accentu=C3=A9, P=
=C3=80F
```

(Every line ends with =) so what I want to grab is literally

```
"=
"
```

I process it with the function pasted below.

But I want to join the lines too, that is remove the line breaks, but I can't get `M-x regexp-builder` to highlight that last "=" sign ***and*** the line break that comes after, so that I can replace it with the empty string "" and thus join the lines..?

```
(setq entities
  '(("=C3=A9" "é")
    ("=C3=89" "É")
    ("=C3=A8" "è")
    ("=C3=88" "È")
    ("=C3=A7" "ç")
    ("=C3=87" "Ç")
    ("=C3=A0" "à")
    ("=C3=80" "À")
    ("=C3=B9" "ù")
    ("=C3=99" "Ù")
    ("=C3=AA" "ê")
    ("=C3=8A" "Ê")
    ("=C3=BB" "û")
    ("=C3=9B" "Û")
    ("=C3=AB" "ë")
    ("=C3=8B" "Ë")
    ("=C3=BC" "ü")
    ("=C3=9C" "Ü")
    ("=20" "")
    ("=3D\"" "=\"")
    ("=$" "")))

(defun px-decode-string (string entities)
  "decode a string against a list of entities / chars pairs."
  (setq i 0)
  (while (< i (length entities))
    (setq my-operand (format "%s" (car (car (nthcdr i entities)))))
    (setq my-char (format "%s" (car (cdr (car (nthcdr i entities))))))
    (setq string (replace-regexp-in-string my-operand my-char string 't))
    (setq i (1+ i))
    )
  (format "%s" string))
```

(The alist is a `setq` and not a `defvar` for testing purposes only)

Test:

```
(px-decode-string "Tiens, encore du HTML, batard rouge, et un charact=C3=A8re accentu=C3=A9, P=
=C3=80F!
" entities)
```

Comment: why don't you use query-replace-regexp ? I am not sure I have understood your querry...

Comment: I see that you try to convert a French text into another coding. Why do not you use the enconding interface of emacs ? Or probably I did not understand what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 3):

In a string literal, you can use "\n" instead of "$" to match the newline.

Interactively, e.g. `query-replace-regexp`, use <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd>.

Comment: Not "instead". "$" is the carriage return alone. "\n" is the carriage return **plus** the newline.

Comment: No.  "instead" is correct.  "$" is an anchor matcher, nothing to do with carriage return.  Try it for yourself!

Comment: Yes. What I meant is if you replace-regexp-in-string "$" with "" the carriage return is still there. If you use "\n" it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

OK, never mind, I found it : `=\n`